# How to get specific information from two text lines and assemble a filename from that

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am currently writing a script to archive a couple log files and want them combined in a single archive which is named according to the first and last lines date and time in one of the log files (i.e. access.log).

But for the best of me I can't wrap my head around how to get this information from the lines and assemble it to a file name.

the lines in question are from an apache.log file which i simply could get with `head` and `tail`:

Example:

```
$ head -n1 /home/server/log/access.log.1 
84.1.11.243 - - [21/Jan/2017:14:53:49 +0000] "GET /index.php/2016/05/26/tutorial-how-to-install-ubuntu-and-other-debian-based-distributions-via-debootstrap/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18413 "https://www.google.hu/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"

$ tail -n1 /home/server/log/access.log.1 
71.3.17.120 - - [20/Dec/2017:16:17:50 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 27639 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; LCTE; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

The expected file name result should be including the date and time stamps from those messages.

Example line I would like to use, but can change that according to the answers results:

```
tar -caf "backup-logfiles-$start-til-$end.tar.gz" access.log error.log ftp.log
```

Any solution is welcome to extract that values into `$start` and `$end`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a horribly convoluted shell one-liner (using the date format you [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41864946#41864946)):

```
$ name=$(printf 'backup-logfiles-%s-til-%s' $(date -d "$(head -n1 logfile | grep -oP '\[\K\S+' | sed 's|/| |g; s/:/ /')" +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S) $(date -d "$(tail -n1 logfile | grep -oP '\[\K\S+' | sed 's|/| |g; s/:/ /')" +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S))
$ echo $name
logfiles-2017-01-21-14:53:49-til-2017-12-20-16:17:50
```

To get the start and end variables separately, do:

```
$ start=$(head -n1 logfile | grep -oP '\[\K\S+' | sed 's|/|-|g; s/:/ /')
$ end=$(tail -n1 logfile | grep -oP '\[\K\S+' | sed 's|/|-|g; s/:/ /')
$ echo "backup-logfiles-$start-til-$end.tar.gz"
backup-logfiles-21-Jan-2017 14:53:49-til-20-Dec-2017 16:17:50.tar.gz
```

Or, if you want a numerical date:

```
$ start=$(date -d "$(head -n1 logfile | grep -oP '\[\K\S+' | sed 's|/|-|g; s/:/ /')" +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)
$ end=$(date -d "$(tail -n1 logfile | grep -oP '\[\K\S+' | sed 's|/|-|g; s/:/ /')" +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)
$ echo "backup-logfiles-$start-til-$end.tar.gz"
backup-logfiles-2017-01-21-14:53:49-til-2017-12-20-16:17:50.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 4):

Using only `sed`, just for <del>fun</del> winning golf ;)

```
name=$(sed -rn 's|/|-|g;s/.* \[([^ ]+) .*/\1/;1p;$p' file | sed 'N;s/\n/-til-/')
$ echo $name
21-Jan-2017:14:53:49-til-20-Dec-2017:16:17:50
```

But if this file is something you want to pass to `tar`, the colons could cause problems:

```
An  archive  name  that has a colon in it specifies a file or device on a remote
machine.  The part before the colon is taken as the machine name or IP address,
and the part after it as the file or device pathname, e.g.:

    --file=remotehost:/dev/sr0
```

You can get around this by passing an option:

```
--force-local
      Archive file is local even if it has a colon.
```

But here's a command that replaces the colons with more hyphens:

```
name=$(sed -rn 's|[/:]|-|g;s/.* \[([^ ]+) .*/\1/;1p;$p' file | sed 'N;s/\n/-til-/')
```

Instead of a character class we could use alternation and save a byte :)

```
name=$(sed -rn 's#/|:#-#g;s/.* \[([^ ]+) .*/\1/;1p;$p' file | sed 'N;s/\n/-til-/')
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `-n` don't print anything until we ask for it
- `s|/|-|g` replace all the `/` characters with `-` (because we can't have a filename with `/`)
- `s|[/:]|-|g` replace `/` and `:` characters with hyphens everywhere.
- `s#/|:#-#g` replace `/` or `:` with `-` everywhere
- `;` separate `sed` commands
- `s/.* \[([^ ]+) .*/\1/` capture the date and time from between the square brackets (from the first `[` to the first space).
- `1p;$p` print just the first line and the last line
- `|` pipe it to another `sed` (ugh!)
- `N` read both lines into the pattern space...
- `s/\n/-til-/` ... so we can replace the newline with `-til-`